# How to use gRPC from PHP and Windows 10 with the "grpc_php_plugin"?

Tags: php, windows, windows-10, grpc

When trying to use gRPC from Windows with PHP, I could find Windows binaries for "protoc.exe" and "php_grpc.dll" but I have not been able to find any "grpc_php_plugin" (exe or dll?) and thus have not succeeded to use gRPC from Windows/PHP.

Documentation page:

https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/php/

The current documentation at the above paqe is unix-oriented (with "make grpc_php_plugin" and "bins/opt" paths in flags such as --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin).

However, it kind of seems as Windows should be supported since the page does mention "Install on Windows  You can download the pre-compiled grpc.dll extension from the PECL website."

On the other hand, if only two of the three needed binaries are available, then it is not enough, since as far as I understand, the following three binaries are needed:

> - "protoc.exe" (indeed available in ["protoc-3.11.4-win64.zip"](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases) )
> - "php_grpc.dll" (indeed is available in ["php_grpc-1.28.0-7.4-nts-vc15-x64.zip"](https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC/1.28.0/windows) )
>     (and I am using 64 bit Windows 10 with nts/non-thread-safe PHP 7.4.4)
> - "grpc_php_plugin" (exe or dll?) NOT (?) available for Windows?

When trying to use the example at the quickstart page, you find this example command:

```
protoc --proto_path=examples/protos --php_out=examples/php --grpc_out=examples/php --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin ./examples/protos/helloworld.proto
```

The problem is the plugin flag "--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin".

When using Windows, you have not compiled with "make grpc_php_plugin" but need to download a binary for Windows and put it in a Windows path instead of the "bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin".

So, if anyone has actually been able to use gRPC for PHP with Windows 10, then please explain to make it work regarding the "grpc_php_plugin" which seems to be needed but not available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **grpc_php_plugin.exe** and some others: https://github.com/aaapi-net/protoc-windows-gen-plugins

Just download it and use the following *command*:

```
protoc -I proto/ --php_out=proto --grpc_out=proto
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=./grpc_php_plugin.exe example.proto
```

Comment: If someone wonder if the above suggestion worked and then why it is not marked as solution:
I do not intend to risk a virus by trying to execute that unknown exe file.
The linked github repository has zero github stars, and it was created and commited to just some hours ago with a bunch of exe files.
The above response was also the first from that stackoverflow user.
If you are truly genuine then sorry but I really expect binaries from grpc (githup repo with 26000+ github stars) to be available (at least linked) from there or at least not just from a new zero stars unknown github repo.

Comment: @user743436 use it in virtualbox)

Comment: If you need stars then compile it according instruction from official repo: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/php/quickstart/#php-protoc-plugin

Answer (score -1):

### Install plugins from more reliable source than git above

1. Download and install http://repo.msys2.org/distrib/x86_64/msys2-x86_64-20200602.exe
2. Open installed Msys2
3. Update packages: `pacman -Su`
4. Install grpc-plugins: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-grpc`
5. Your plugins are here: *C:\msys64\mingw64\bin*

### or

1. You can just download http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/mingw-w64-x86_64-grpc-1.29.1-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
2. Open it with zstd plugin http://facebook.github.io/zstd/